# How to configure and run Eureka Server, Microservices (Eureka Client), Zuul inside separate docker containers?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, containers, microservices

I am a newbie in Spring Boot and Docker. 
Written the below microservices.

1. **User Registration Service**: Create users in the MySql database and also interacts with "Search and Delete Service" using Rest Template and its Eureka Client. GitHub [link](https://github.com/git4suvendu/UserRegistrationMicroservice/tree/multiInstanceMicroservice)
2. **User Search and Delete Service**: Search and Delete from MySql database and its Eureka Client. GitHub [Link](https://github.com/git4suvendu/UserSearchDeleteMicroservice)
3. **Eureka Server**: Used for service discovery. GitHub [Link](https://github.com/git4suvendu/UserRegistrationEurekaServer)
4. **Zuul Server**: Used as an API Gateway and its Eureka Client. GitHub [Link](https://github.com/git4suvendu/ZuulAPIGateway)

I have used "Spring Boot STS" to develop the services. Also used "Spotify" dependency to build the docker images.

I am able to run all the services from STS on localhost (windows) and everything is working fine. All the three services mentioned before are getting registered in Eureka server.

But everything stopped working when I choose to dockerize the services. I have created four docker images of the four services.

**Problem:** Ran the Eureka server and "User Registration Service" in two sperate containers but the service is not getting registered with Eureka. In fact none of the services is getting registered with Eureka.

**What I did:**

### Try 1:

```
Ran the Eureka server and client using below commands:
```

> docker run --rm -it --name eurekaserver-container -p 8761:8761
>   eurekaserver-alpine-linux
>
> docker run --rm -it -d --name user-registration-container -p 8081:8081
>   user-registration

[image]

It seems Eureka Client (User Registration Service) is not able to find Eureka server. What I found, Eureka server is running within a container with different IP (172.0...) and Eureka client is not able to connect the server.

### Try 2:

Ran the Eureka server and client using below commands. Tried to link the two containers (Eureka Server and Client):

> docker run --rm -it --name eurekaserver-container -p 8761:8761
>   eurekaserver-alpine-linux
>
> docker run --rm -it -d --name user-registration-container -p 8081:8081
>   --link eurekaserver-container:eureka-server user-registration

This also didn't work.

[Try 2 Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/How9N.jpg)

### Try 3:

Ran the Eureka server and client using below commands. Tried to pass the host name to Eureka image, so that Client can find the Eureka server using host name. Also linked the two containers.

> docker run --rm -it -d  --name eurekaserver-container -h 
>   discovery-eurekaserver.com  -p 8761:8761 eurekaserver-alpine-linux
>   /bin/bash
>
> docker run --rm -it -d  --name user-registration-container -p
>   8081:8081 --link eurekaserver-container:eureka-server
>   user-registration

[Try 3 Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAdXL.jpg)

This also didn't work.

**Can anyone please help me to understand what am I doing wrong?** Whatever I have tried, Eureka clients are not able to register with Eureka server when running in different containers.

My objective is to run the services (Eureka Server, Application Services etc.) in different containers and all the services will register with Eureka server, so that I can call APIs from Postman or SOAP UI.

Comment: What is the error response for try 2 and try 3 ?

Comment: Its same as Try 1.

Comment: if that is the error log of the client then Eureka Server or whatever the client tries to reach should be bind to `0.0.0.0` so other containers can reach it. as the log says connection refused which means that the client cannot reach the server because there is no service listen on that port through the container ip. check the configuration file of the service itself in order to configure it

Comment: After running Eureka Server container, I ran the below command. Rocks@Rocks-Lapi MINGW64 /c/Program Files/Docker Toolbox
$ docker inspect -f '{{.Name}} - {{.NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' $(docker ps -
aq)
/eurekaserver-container - 172.17.0.2

Comment: After running Eureka Server container, I ran the below command. Rocks@Rocks-Lapi MINGW64 /c/Program Files/Docker Toolbox
$ docker inspect -f '{{.Name}} - {{.NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' $(docker ps -
aq)
**/eurekaserver-container - 172.17.0.2** . So, it means Eureka is running on 172.17.0.2 IP which is nothing but a container ip.  But in the Eureka server properties file I have written "eureka.instance.hostname=discovery-eurekaserver.com" . discovery-eurekaserver.com is 127.0.0.1 in the windows hosts file. Before runnig the container how do I mention the ip in the properties file?

Comment: the following url is for a client but try it for the server
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/432#issuecomment-120661200

Comment: Apologies, I am not clear from the github link. What am I suppose to change?  Should I mention eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true in the Eureka server properties file?

Comment: I guess it should be in application.properties

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest, you have a separate Dockerfile for each Spring boot project.

```
FROM maven:3.6.0-jdk-8
MAINTAINER xxx@yyyyy.com
COPY . /usr/src/project-name
WORKDIR /usr/src/project-name
CMD ["mvn","spring-boot:run"]
```

And a docker-compose.yml for controlling services and networks and links between containers.

For example:

```
version: '3.5'
services:

  discovery-server:
    build:
      context: ./discovery-server
    hostname: discovery-server
    environment:
      - SPRING_APPLICATION_NAME=discovery-server
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev
    command: ["mvn", "spring-boot:run"]
    expose:
      - "8761"
    volumes:
      - maven-home:/root/.m2
    networks:
      services-network-01:
        aliases:
          - discovery-server

  user-service:
    build:
      context: ./user-service
    hostname: user-service
    environment:
      - SPRING_APPLICATION_NAME=user-service
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev
    command: ["mvn", "spring-boot:run"]
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - maven-home:/root/.m2
    networks:
      services-network-01:
        aliases:
          - user-service
    depends_on:
      - discovery-server

volumes:
  maven-home:

networks:
  services-network-01:
    name: services-network-01
    driver: bridge
```

[Docker Compose File Refrence](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/)

And ultimately depends on the configuration for Eureka discovery server and Microservices.

Eureka Discovery Server config in `application.yml`:

```
server:
  port: 8761
eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: false
    region: region1
    serviceUrl:
      zone1: http://discovery-server:8761/eureka/
    availability-zones:
      region1: zone1
  instance:
    hostname: discovery-server
    metadata-map:
      zone: zone1
```

Eureka client config in `application.yml` in Microservices:

```
# Eureka client
eureka:
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address: true
    metadata-map:
      zone: zone1
  client:
    prefer-same-zone-eureka: true
    register-with-eureka: true
    region: region1
    service-url:
      zone1: http://discovery-server:8761/eureka/
    availability-zones:
      region1: zone1
```

Run docker compose:

```
docker-compose up -d --build --force-recreate
```

[Docker Compose Commands Refrence](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/)

Comment: http://discovery-server-01:8761/eureka/ How this will be replaced by the container ip?

Comment: In docker networking,docker compose creates a new bridge network that controls DNS and hostnames.

Comment: By default Compose sets up a single network for your app. Each container for a service joins the default network and is both reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by them at a hostname identical to the container name.https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Comment: I will try this now and feedback you. Thanks.

Comment: just a clarification required. In your docker-compose.yml how are you calling Docker file? If I just push the .jar file in the image will that do?  Like this:  **FROM java:8-alpine
RUN apk --no-cache add netcat-openbsd
COPY /UserSearch-0.0.1.jar /opt/lib/
COPY /UserSearchDelete.sh /opt/bin/UserSearchDelete.sh
RUN chmod 755 /opt/bin/UserSearchDelete.sh
EXPOSE 8082**

Comment: It worked fine !! Thanks. Git updated. https://github.com/git4suvendu/UserRegistrationEurekaServer/tree/master/DockerFiles

Comment: Great.If your problem is solved, you can tick the answer.